# I can't call a method from inside a function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet

I am beginner with typescript. 
I got a problem when I try to call the method drawMarker() from locateMe(). 
I think the problem is that I am calling drawMarker from inside the .on('locationfound', function(e: any){}

EXCEPTION: this.drawMarker is not a function

the drawMarker works, I sucessefully called it from other methods

My two methods inside my component class:

```
drawMarker(item: any, elementId: any) {
    if (elementId === 'inpStartWayPoint') {
        if (typeof(this.startMarker) === 'undefined') {
            this.startMarker = L.marker([parseFloat(item.lat), parseFloat(item.lon)]);
            this.map.addLayer(this.startMarker);
            this.startMarker.bindPopup('Départ').openPopup();
        } else {
            this.startMarker.setLatLng(([parseFloat(item.lat), parseFloat(item.lon)]));
        }
        //this.map.removeLayer(this.startMarker);


    } else if (elementId === 'inpEndWayPoint') {
        if (typeof(this.endMarker) === 'undefined') {
            this.endMarker = L.marker([parseFloat(item.lat), parseFloat(item.lon)]);
            this.map.addLayer(this.endMarker);
            this.endMarker.bindPopup('Arrivée').openPopup();
        } else {
            this.endMarker.setLatLng(([parseFloat(item.lat), parseFloat(item.lon)]));
        }

    } else if (elementId === 'locateMyPosition') {

        if (typeof(this.geoLocateMarker) === 'undefined') {
            this.geoLocateMarker = L.marker([item.latitude, item.longitude]);

            this.map.addLayer(this.geoLocateMarker);
            this.geoLocateMarker.bindPopup('Votre Position').openPopup();
        } else {
            this.geoLocateMarker.setLatLng([item.latitude, item.longitude]);
        }

    }

}
locateMe(elementId: any) {
    this.map.locate({
            setView: true,
            watch: true
        }) /* This will return map so you can do chaining */
        .on('locationfound', function(e: any) {
            // var marker = L.marker([e.latitude, e.longitude]).bindPopup('Your are here :)');
            var circle = L.circle([e.latitude, e.longitude], e.accuracy / 2, {
                weight: 1,
                color: 'blue',
                fillColor: '#ca08c9',
                fillOpacity: 0.2
            });
            console.log([e.latitude]);
            this.drawMarker(e, elementId);
            //this.map.addLayer(marker);
            this.map.addLayer(circle);
        })
        .on('locationerror', function(e: any) {
            console.log(e);
            alert("Location access denied.");
        });
}
```

my html input with the boutton locateMe :

```
<div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><button type="button" id="locateMyPosition" title='Locate Me !'
                                                    (click)="locateMe('locateMyPosition')"><i
              class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></button></span>

            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Départ" value="" id="inpStartWayPoint">
            <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button"
                                                  (click)="adressAutoComplete('inpStartWayPoint')"><i
              class="fa fa-search"></i></button></span>

          </div>
```

Thank you in advance for any help you can give me !

Comment: [This (hah)](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/'this'-in-TypeScript) might come in handy for issues with `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` changes context inside `function`, try using arrow functions instead, it keeps `this` context.

Something like this:

```
this.map.locate({ setView: true, watch: true })       .on('locationfound',  (e: any) => { // using arrow function here
    var circle = L.circle([e.latitude, e.longitude], e.accuracy / 2, {
      weight: 1,
      color: 'blue',
      fillColor: '#ca08c9',
      fillOpacity: 0.2
    });
    console.log([e.latitude]);
    this.drawMarker(e, elementId);
    this.map.addLayer(circle);
  })
  .on('locationerror',  (e: any) => {
    console.log(e);
    alert("Location access denied.");
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda to keep your reference to `this`:

```
.on('locationfound', (e: any) => {
     ...
}
```

Comment: Works great Thank you ^^